# Loop always starting at 0,0 - Trying to solve "Longest Increasing Path in a Matrix". What am i not seeing?

Tags: python, matrix, data-structures, depth-first-search, memoization

I have been struggling to solve this leetcode question here: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-path-in-a-matrix/

My code here: https://pastebin.com/QBcXrbJa

The question is basically asking for the longest "path" given a matrix. I have added what I expected the code wants

We have an isValid function thats inside solver() that checks

- the current row/column is within the matrix
- the current nodes value is larger than the last
- we have not seen it before

If it checks out, numPath (the variable that counts the length of the path) gets increased, we add the node to visited, and we continue checking all nodes around it

However....

1. I am getting an incorrect output (example, the matrix [[9,9,4],[6,6,8],[2,1,1]] outputs 2 instead of the expected output of 4)
2. From my debug code, I noticed that the first 4 visited is always (0,0), even if we do not start at (0, 0)

For example, in the main function, we have

```
    for rowKey in range(0, matrixR):
        for colKey in range(0, matrixC):
            longest.append(
                solver(matrix, rowKey, colKey, matrixR, matrixC, matrix[rowKey][colKey])
            )
```

which is supposed to change where the code starts, but thats not reflected in the debug code

Debug Output

```
Row: 0 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 0 - visited: []
Row: 1 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0)]
Row: -1 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0)]        
Row: 0 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0)]
Row: 0 - Col: -1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0)]        
Row: 0 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0)]
Row: 1 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1)] 
Row: -1 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
Row: 0 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
Row: 0 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 9 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
Row: 0 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 4 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 4 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
Row: 2 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 0 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 1 - Col: 3 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 1 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: -1 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 4 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 0 - Col: 3 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 4 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 0 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 4 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 1 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
Row: 2 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0)]
Row: 0 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0)]
Row: 1 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0)]
Row: 1 - Col: -1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0)]
Row: 2 - Col: -1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
Row: 0 - Col: -1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
Row: 1 - Col: -2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
Row: 2 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
Row: 0 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 6 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
Row: 2 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 2 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
Row: 3 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 2 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
Row: 2 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 2 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
Row: 2 - Col: -1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 2 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
Row: 2 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
Row: 3 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
Row: 1 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
Row: 2 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
Row: 2 - Col: 0 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
Row: 2 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 0 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
Row: 3 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
Row: 1 - Col: 2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
Row: 2 - Col: 3 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
Row: 2 - Col: 1 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 1 - numPath: 1 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
2
```

What is my problem?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  Your posted code does not run.  Your example is not minimal.

Comment: Hi, i will fix that but I just copied my code now and in fact does run and im asking 2 specific questions

Comment: No, it does not run.  The very first line dies because `matrixR` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main problems:
The array of visited coordinates are not reset each time the solver is called in the main. Looking at your debug output, the visited array only gets bigger with each line.

The isValid function does not verify if the coordinates are inferior to the matrix. You can see the row and col values dipping into the negative twice here:

```
Row: 1 - Col: -2 - RowMax: 3 - ColMax: 3 - currVal: 8 - numPath: 2 - visited: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
```